# Flutter App is Crashing After Installation

Tags: xcode, firebase, flutter, flutter-ios

I'm getting this error...
Unable to solve this. Please help
App just crashed after installation.

What I have tried:

1. Added Google-services.plist from xcode
2. Add/Remo FirebaseApp.configure() in AppDelegate.swift
3. Added GMSServices.provideAPIKey()

````
flutter: getCurrentLocation
flutter: {app_name: , default_tax: null, default_currency: null, currency_right: false, enable_paypal: true, enable_stripe: true, mobile_language: en}
flutter: getCurrentLocation
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c710bc +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   location                            0x000000010aeee80c -[LocationPlugin requestPermission] + 460
    4   location                            0x000000010aeeddf9 -[LocationPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] + 2137
    5   Flutter                             0x0000000108bd6f32 __45-[FlutterMethodChannel setMethodCallHandler:]_block_invoke + 104
    6   Flutter                             0x0000000108b65a4e _ZNK7flutter21PlatformMessageRouter21HandlePlatformMess<…>
Lost connection to device.```



I'm using this source code ( https://codecanyon.net/item/multi-restaurants-flutter-php-laravel-admin-panel/24878940 )
````

Answer (score 0):

Step 2 and 3 can skip,

Please sure register app id to firebase. Copy Google-Services.plist to ios/Runner and drag to xcode for register file.

And run **flutter clean** in terminal for clear build failed.